# How to access parent component ExtJS?

Tags: javascript, extjs, scope

For some reason, the blur event doesn't get fired when the below floating panel loses focus. However, when I listen to the 'el' of the panel for the blur event, it gets registered as shown in the listeners config. What I want to do is hide the panel when the blur event occurs. How do I get access to the parent panel ?

```
Ext.define('NoteKeeper.view.tabs.AttachmentPanel',{
    extend : 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    alias : 'widget.attachmentPanel',
    itemId : 'attachmentPanel',
    floating : true,
    focusable : true,
    width : 200,
    height : 150,
    layout : {
        type : 'vbox'
    },
    items : [
        {
            xtype : 'grid',
            store : null,
            columns : [
                {
                    text : 'File Name',
                    dataIndex : 'fileName'
                },
                {
                    dataIndex : 'remove'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            xtype : 'button',
            text : '+'
        }
    ],
    listeners : {
        el: {
            blur: {
                fn: function()
                {
                    console.log( this );
                    //how do I access the 'attachmentPanel' from here 
                    //so I can hide it ?
                }
            }
        }
    },
    noteId : null,
    initComponent : function()
    {
        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

Please note that there can be multiple instances of these 'attachmentPanel's.

Comment: Use the `focusleave` event on the component: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/25d2

Comment: @EvanTrimboli Unfortunately, above doesn't work. When I click on the + sign and somewhere inside the floating panel, the blur event is still fired. It appears, the focus is attached to the button inside the panel, and not the panel itself. Attaching the blur to the el works better but clicking on the button causes the el to loose focus. Do you know a way around that ?

Answer (score 0):

The following appears to work fine:

```
listeners : {
        el: {
            blur: {
                fn: function()
                {
                    console.log(this);
                    var elId = this.id;
                    var attachmentPanels = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#attachmentPanel');
                    Ext.Array.forEach( attachmentPanels, function(cmp){
                        if(cmp.id == elId)
                        {
                            cmp.hide();
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }
```

Please let me know if there is better/more efficient solution. Thanks!

Comment: you can use focus leave and get component as you want [click](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/25d7)

Answer (score -1):

There is a reference from the element to the owning component, in form of the `component` property, so from the scope of the element, you can access the panel like so:

```
var attachmentPanel = this.component;
```